# Get existing AudioContext in aframe

Tags: three.js, aframe, web-audio-api

I'm trying to work with audio using the WebAudioAPI and aframe. I should be able to connect a new Convolver Node or any other AudioNode to the existing Audio Context created, if I understood correctly, by THREE.js. How can I get thee reference of the context in Javascript?

I tried to search in the docs of aframe and THREE.js but it seems like evry example make you create a new node. Maybe I'm missing some exposed property on the Scene?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik `a-frame`s [sound component uses THREE.AudioLoader](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v1.4.0/src/components/sound.js#L31) which [utilizes](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/AudioLoader.js#L30) an [existing or newly created](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/audio/AudioContext.js#L3) audio context.

So I'd try grabbing

```
const context = THREE.AudioContext.getContext();
```

to get the context that is used / will be used by the AudioLoader.